# Jmeter Recording/playback issue

Tags: jmeter

I am newbie in jmeter, I recorded script in firefox using HTTPS Test Script recorder and, my test scenario involved creating objects in UI. 
Script passed while playing back this scenario, but I don't see any such objects created in UI or in DB.

Why did script passed if there was no objects created?

Appreciate reply.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Recording through JMeter (or any other tool) and then replaying is not enough, you need to do after recording some correlation work:

- Extract ids from some responses and inject them in next requests
- Variabilize some data to put them in CSV (login , password ...)
- Add timers
- Add assertions to check

Answer (score 0):

Does your Web Application supports *Cookie*? Add ***Cookie*** element to your Test Plan and Play it back(Add it after HTTP Request Defaults)